# Centering image in CSS

Tags: css, image, centering

In the following, I want to center image and quote. Although I have managed to do so, their position in the center is slightly different. How can I make them be precisely in the center and image exactly under quote?
Thanks in advance.

[Here is my problem](https://codepen.io/ErolAliyev/pen/XROORq)

HTML:

```
<p id="quote">It is not who I am underneath, but what I do that defines me</p>
```

`<img src="http://comiconverse.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/The-Dark-Knight.jpg">`

CSS:

```
img {
max-width: 40%;
max-height: 40%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-radius: 50%;
float: left; }

#quote {
text-align: center; }
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution but unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmLLLX - if you want to move the navs down, just add top margin to them.  I have added wrapper so that you get a distinct left, center and right column

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VbggJL - if you want 25%/50%/25% page layout around your image

Comment: add display: block; margin: 0 auto; in your css

Comment: `margin-left: somenumberofpx;`

Comment: @gaynorvader  thank you! that was exactly what I wanted to do.